# Prevent event.click from triggering event.mousemove in Safari

Tags: jquery

It seems that in jQuery, a click event on an element will automatically trigger a mousemove event for that element as well. Is there any way to prevent this?

Here is the most basic test case I could put together. For me, using a trackpad, a click on the box triggers the mousemove event. And I did not notice any movement in the mouse cursor.

http://jsfiddle.net/nay5d/

**UPDATE: I have tested the code in both Safari, Chrome, and Firefox. In Safari, a click triggers mousemove. In Chrome/Firefox, it seems that a click DOES NOT trigger mousemove. Interesting.**

Comment: I can't confirm that; When you are over the object mousemove triggers. When you remain still and perform a click, only the click event fires. -- Do you have any code that can demonstrate the problem you're having?

Comment: Have a steady hand ;) I can't reproduce it either: http://jsfiddle.net/tzkAs/

Comment: @cmal - I'm not seeing the results you are getting. I updated @Felix's code by triggering the click() and mousemove() programmatically (to remove the "shakiness" of the mouse). No mousemove is triggered via a click. http://jsfiddle.net/tzkAs/2/

Comment: @JasCav What browser were you testing in? As I say in my updated question, click only activates a mousemove in Safari.

Comment: @cmal - I'm testing in Chrome and IE. However, I'm *not* testing by actually clicking. I'm firing them programmatically (per my jsFiddle link). Is mousemove still firing even when you do it programmatically (not by physically clicking the mouse)? I did some research online and didn't find any problems with what you are describing in an Safari bugs.

Comment: @JasCav: I tested it in Safari (manually) and the mousemove event is indeed fired. I'm using a touchpad with separate button (old white Macbook) so that my click would move the mouse is excluded. Very interesting indeed. Maybe this is worth a bug report somewhere (jQuery or Safari).

Comment: This is not a jQuery bug btw. It seems to be a problem with Safari. The same problem exists using "plain" JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/tzkAs/3/

Comment: @cmal This is a Webkit but. A mouse click will trigger the mousemove event in Safari and Chrome, but not in IE9, Firefox or Opera.

Comment: @cmal @Felix @Sime - Strange. I don't get the mousemove problem in my version of Chrome (11 beta) nor in the most recent build of Chromium. (Like you, Felix, I used a separate mouse button for the click to separate the movement of the mouse.) Strange indeed.

Comment: @Sime: As said, the problem does not occur in Chrome.

Comment: @Felix @JasCav The issue occurs in my Chrome (version 10, Windows 7).

Comment: @Sime: Oh ok. Then it gets even more interesting ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same result using a legacy method in Safari, as well. The extra `mouseMove` event is being triggered on `mouseUp`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/s7r8d/

```
document.onmousemove = function(mouseEvent) {
    mouseEvent || (mouseEvent = window.event);
    var target = mouseEvent.target || mouseEvent.srcElement;
    if (target.id=="dom") {
        target.className = target.className=="highlight"
            ? ""
            : "highlight";
    }
}
```

Even trying to coerce the `mouseUp` event is unsuccessful. We can try reporting this bug to Apple to fix if it indeed is a Safari bug.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran a few tests, and I don't feel like this is what is happening. If you don't register a mousemove event with an element, then no event will fire. If you ARE registering a mousemove event, then you should be aware than the littlest bit of mouse movement (including the movement that happens when you click the object) will cause the mousemove event to be fired.

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you may want to look into [one of the many other mouse events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/), or accomplish your functionality in a completely different manner. (If you post what your ultimate goal is for this bit of functionality, I can try to help you with that.)

Comment: In Chrome a mouse click will trigger the mousemove event even if you don't move the mouse at all. You can test this by holding the mouse in mid air while clicking it - the mousemove event will still fire (moving the mouse in mid air does not trigger the mousemove event).

Answer (score 1):

Hy guys, I tried like this and seems to work, at least in chrome

http://jsfiddle.net/ZNHDT/

```
$('h1').bind('mousemove', swapClass);

function swapClass() {
    $('h1').toggleClass('highlight');
}

$('h1').mousedown(function(ev){
    $("h1").unbind("mousemove");
    console.log("pippo");
})
$('h1').mouseup(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    $("h1").bind("mousemove", swapClass);
    },10);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think not, as long as your mouse is on the click area, you'll be firing the mousemove event too.

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/3KHQG/